useQuery React still fires when enabled is false
I am having an issue when I try to execute dependent query.
This is the code of the component that only show info from the API REST using react-query, even when the enabled is set to false i am seeing on the browser
Browser tools:
GET https://localhost:7065/api/Location/cityById/undefined
[HTTP/2 400  226ms]

XHRGET
https://localhost:7065/api/Location/parishById/undefined
[HTTP/2 400  212ms]

XHRGET
https://localhost:7065/api/Location/townShipById/undefined
[HTTP/2 400  128ms]

XHRGET
https://localhost:7065/api/Location/zoneTypeById/undefined
[HTTP/2 400  181ms]

XHRGET
https://localhost:7065/api/Location/cityById/undefined
[HTTP/2 400  209ms]

XHRGET
https://localhost:7065/api/Location/parishById/undefined
[HTTP/2 400  155ms]

XHRGET
https://localhost:7065/api/Location/zoneTypeById/undefined
[HTTP/2 400  232ms]

XHRGET
https://localhost:7065/api/Location/townShipById/undefined

Code of component:
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { useRegisterFormViewContext } from "../providers/registerFormViewProvider";
import { useAuth } from "../hooks/useAuth";
import { GetStoreDetailService } from "../services/storeDetailService";
import { GetEstimateService } from "../services/estimateService";
import {
  GetCityByIdService,
  GetParishedByIdService,
  GetStatesService,
  GetTwonShipByIdService,
  GetZoneTypesByIdService,
} from "../services/locationSerivce";

function ViewStoreDetail() {
  const { storedValue } = useAuth();

  const [state] = useRegisterFormViewContext();

  const { data: viewDetailStore, isPending: isPendingViewDetailStore } =
    useQuery({
      queryKey: ["viewStoreDetail"],
      queryFn: GetStoreDetailService(
        storedValue,
        state.select_store_id.select_store_id,
      ),
      staleTime: 0,
      enabled: true,
    });

  const { data: estimateData, isPending: isPendingEstimateData } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["viewStoreDetailEstimate"],
    queryFn: GetEstimateService(storedValue),
    staleTime: 0,
    enabled: true,
  });

  const { data: states, isPending: isPendingStates } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["viewStoreDetailStates"],
    queryFn: GetStatesService(storedValue),
    staleTime: 0,
    enabled: true,
  });

  const cityId = viewDetailStore?.std_dir_city_id;

  const { data: city, isPending: isPendingCity } = useQuery({
    enabled: false,
    queryKey: ["viewStoreDetailCity", cityId],
    queryFn: GetCityByIdService(storedValue, cityId),
    staleTime: 0,
  });

  const parishedId = viewDetailStore?.std_dir_parroquia_id;

  const { data: parished, isPending: isPendingParisged } = useQuery({
    enabled: false,
    queryKey: ["viewStoreDetailParished", parishedId],
    queryFn: GetParishedByIdService(storedValue, parishedId),
    staleTime: 0,
  });

  const townshipId = parished?.par_tow_id;

  const { data: township, isPending: isPendingTownShip } = useQuery({
    enabled: false,
    queryKey: ["viewStoreDetailTownship", townshipId],
    queryFn: GetTwonShipByIdService(storedValue, townshipId),
    staleTime: 0,
  });

  const transportId = viewDetailStore?.std_dir_zone_type_id;

  const { data: transportType, isPending: isPendingTransportType } = useQuery({
    enabled: false,
    queryKey: ["viewStoreDetailTransporType", transportId],
    queryFn: GetZoneTypesByIdService(storedValue, transportId),
    staleTime: 0,
  });

  return (
    <div className="h-[calc(100vh-64px)] border-2 border-black">
      SHOW information of the queries in the future...
    </div>
  );
}

export default ViewStoreDetail;

Here are my API calls:
import { GetBaseUrl } from "./apiBaseUrl";

export async function GetStatesService(storedValue) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(GetBaseUrl() + "api/Location/states", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${storedValue}`,
      },
    });

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
    }

    return response.json();
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error("Obtener estados fallo: " + error.message);
  }
}

export async function GetCitiesByStateService(storedValue, stateId) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      GetBaseUrl() + `api/Location/citiesByState/${stateId}`,
      {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
          Authorization: `Bearer ${storedValue}`,
        },
      },
    );

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
    }

    return response.json();
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error("Obtener ciudades fallo: " + error.message);
  }
}

export async function GetCityByIdService(storedValue, cityId) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      GetBaseUrl() + `api/Location/cityById/${cityId}`,
      {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
          Authorization: `Bearer ${storedValue}`,
        },
      },
    );

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
    }

    return response.json();
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error("Obtene ciudad fallo: " + error.message);
  }
}

export async function GetTwonShipsByStateService(storedValue, stateId) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      GetBaseUrl() + `api/Location/townShipsByState/${stateId}`,
      {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
          Authorization: `Bearer ${storedValue}`,
        },
      },
    );

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
    }

    return response.json();
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error("Obtener municipios fallo: " + error.message);
  }
}

export async function GetTwonShipByIdService(storedValue, twonShipId) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      GetBaseUrl() + `api/Location/townShipById/${twonShipId}`,
      {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
          Authorization: `Bearer ${storedValue}`,
        },
      },
    );

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
    }

    return response.json();
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error("Obtene municipio fallo: " + error.message);
  }
}

export async function GetParishedByTownShipService(storedValue, townShipId) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      GetBaseUrl() + `api/Location/parishesByTownShip/${townShipId}`,
      {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
          Authorization: `Bearer ${storedValue}`,
        },
      },
    );

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
    }

    return response.json();
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error("Obtener parroquias fallo: " + error.message);
  }
}

export async function GetParishedByIdService(storedValue, parishedId) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      GetBaseUrl() + `api/Location/parishById/${parishedId}`,
      {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
          Authorization: `Bearer ${storedValue}`,
        },
      },
    );

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
    }

    return response.json();
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error("Obtene parroquia fallo: " + error.message);
  }
}

export async function GetZoneTypesService(storedValue) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(GetBaseUrl() + "api/Location/zoneTypes", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${storedValue}`,
      },
    });

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
    }

    return response.json();
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error("Obtener tipos de zonas fallo: " + error.message);
  }
}

export async function GetZoneTypesByIdService(storedValue, zoneTypeId) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      GetBaseUrl() + `api/Location/zoneTypeById/${zoneTypeId}`,
      {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
          Authorization: `Bearer ${storedValue}`,
        },
      },
    );

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
    }

    return response.json();
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error("Obtener tipo de zona fallo: " + error.message);
  }
}

Here is my App.jsx:
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import Homepage from "./pages/Homepage";
import Login from "./pages/Login";
import EmptyLayaout from "./layaout/EmptyLayaout";
import AppLayaout from "./layaout/AppLayaout";
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { ReactQueryDevtools } from "@tanstack/react-query-devtools";
import { AuthProvider } from "./hooks/useAuth";
import PrivateRoute from "./pages/PrivateRoute";
import Users from "./pages/Users";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
import { ToastContainer } from "react-toastify";
import ViewStoreDetail from "./pages/ViewStoreDetail";
import UpdateStoreDetail from "./pages/UpdateStoreDetail";
import SelectViewStoreDetail from "./pages/SelectViewStoreDetail";
import RegisterFormViewProvider from "./providers/registerFormViewProvider";

const queryClient = new QueryClient({
  defaultOptions: {
    queries: {
      staleTime: 60 * 1000,
      enabled: false,
    },
  },
});

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    element: <EmptyLayaout />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/login",
        element: <Login />,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    element: <AppLayaout />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/",
        element: (
          <PrivateRoute redirectTo="/login">
            <Homepage />
          </PrivateRoute>
        ),
      },
      {
        path: "/view-store",
        element: (
          <PrivateRoute redirectTo="/login">
            <SelectViewStoreDetail />
          </PrivateRoute>
        ),
      },
      {
        path: "/view-store-detail-resume",
        element: (
          <PrivateRoute redirectTo="/login">
            <ViewStoreDetail />
          </PrivateRoute>
        ),
      },
      {
        path: "/update-store",
        element: (
          <PrivateRoute redirectTo="/login">
            <UpdateStoreDetail />
          </PrivateRoute>
        ),
      },
      {
        path: "/users",
        element: (
          <PrivateRoute redirectTo="/login">
            <Users />
          </PrivateRoute>
        ),
      },
    ],
  },
]);

function App() {
  return (
    <RegisterFormViewProvider>
      <AuthProvider>
        <ToastContainer />
        <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
          <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen={false} position="right" />
          <RouterProvider router={router} />
        </QueryClientProvider>
      </AuthProvider>
    </RegisterFormViewProvider>
  );
}

export default App;

I don't know why it keeps firing the queries if enabled is set to false

Looking at this component, in each useQuery call, you invoke the service function directly within queryFn rather than passing it as a function to be called when the query runs. This approach immediately executes the function on the component mount, ignoring enabled: false.
Try this and make similar changes to other queries


const { data: viewDetailStore, isPending: isPendingViewDetailStore } = useQuery({
  queryKey: ["viewStoreDetail"],
  queryFn: () => GetStoreDetailService(
    storedValue,
    state.select_store_id.select_store_id,
  ),
  staleTime: 0,
  enabled: true,
});



